# New DynamoDB attribute can't be queried from Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena, dynamodb-queries

I had a DynamoDB with 6 attributes (integers and strings), created an Athena data source through federated queries and everything was fine.

Recently, I added a `List`-type attribute to the DynamoDB table. The 7 attributes appear successfully when I use DynamoDB's built-in query. However, when I try to query DynamoDB from Athena, I find the original 6 columns but not the new List attribute (tried fetching the last few rows that contain the new attribute, but still).

I tried creating another data source and another lambda function, but I still can't get the new attribute when I `select *`, and `select "new_attribute_name"` returns a `COLUMN_NOT_FOUND`.

I considered dropping the entire table and starting a fresh one with the 7 attributes. But I wanted to ask here first before doing it. How do I get Athena to see the new DynamoDB attribute?

Comment: How much data is in your table?

Comment: Very small, about 500 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Athena connector does a discover for the schema it only samples 5 items AFAIR. So if you've added an extra attribute to only some items but not all, then it will not appear in your queries as it's not considered a part of the schema. To overcome it, you can manually create your table in the Glue Catalog and use that in Athena.

Comment: Since it only samples 5 (or n) items, can I update all items by setting the 7th attribute to `[ ]` or nulls to make it work?

Comment: That would also work I guess, but you need to be aware you cannot guarantee that item will always be in the same position if you are adding more items to the table.